# How do i allow my class's instances to be seen in a data source Visual basic C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Forgive me I am new and I'm sure its something trivial but,
I have a data grid in a form that I want to display data from a separate class.
this is the class with the data, the data I am talking about is the variables (name, money ect.).

```
public class Player
{
    public Player() { }

    public Player(string s, Square square)
    {
        name = s;
        location = square; 
    }

    int money;
    public int Money
    {
        get { return money; }
        set { money = value; }
    }

    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    } 

    Square location = new Square();
    public Square Location
    { 
        get { return location; }
        set { location  = value; }
    } 

    Image playerTokenImage;
    public Image PlayerTokenImage
    {
        get { return playerTokenImage; }
        set { playerTokenImage = value; } 
    }

    bool hasWon;
    public bool HasWon
    {
        get { return hasWon; }
        set { hasWon = value; } 
    }

    private Brush playerTokenColour;
    public Brush PlayerTokenColour
    { 
        get { return playerTokenColour;}
        set
        {
            playerTokenColour = value;
            playerTokenImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);

            using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(playerTokenImage)) 
            {
                g.FillRectangle(playerTokenColour, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when I try to select this class as an object data source for my DataGridView only `money` and `hasWon` are visible, like this: [DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEPsQ.png)
Anyone know why the other variables are not visible? please request more information if needed.

Comment: If you change `Name` to `Name2`, does it appear?

Comment: @YoryeNathan nope  :(

Comment: What if you don't choose a datasource type for the grid, and bind it to a `List<Player>` on run-time?

Comment: I was thinking it was because my variables aren't in c# property format or whatever but I have been comparing to working examples and they look fine.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do what you described

Comment: new information though, I removed the `money` variable completely and the grid still displayed `money` and `hasWon`. I am thinking it is a VB problem now

Comment: Right click the solution in the solution explorer > Clean solution. Then again right click > Build All.

Comment: Thanks that solved it! <3

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments but all I had to do was rebuild the solution.